# Retrieve a value from ResourceDictionary in code behind

Tags: xaml, windows-10, resourcedictionary, uwp

I have a Windows 10 universal app with a few resource dictionaries for styles and such. 
In one such resource dictionary, I have a color, `MyBlue` that I want to access via the code behind. How is this achieved?

I've tried `this.Resources["MyBlue"]`, but since `MyBlue` is defined in a separate resource dictionary and not directly in the page resources it doesn't exist in this collection.

Here's my app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/PodStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/ButtonStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/OfferStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/MyStyles.xaml"/>

            <ResourceDictionary>
                <!--Global View Model Locator-->
                <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                                     d:IsDataSource="True"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MergedDictionaries are available via `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries`.

I was able to obtain the appropriate ResourceDictionary by Uri and then access the item in it by key name:

```
var mergedDict = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Where(md => md.Source.AbsoluteUri == "ms-resource:///Files/Styles/MyStyles.xaml").FirstOrDefault();
newColor = (Windows.UI.Color)mergedDict["MyBlue"];
```

Comment: Can you share your app.xaml? This shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Uh... :confused: I have no idea. That looks correct, and you should be able to reach it by just looking at the application's resources.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried

```
Application.Current.Resources["MyBlue"]
```

Comment: There are no items in that Resources collection.

Answer (score 3):

I will try to sum-up all the solution as all previous solution seems to have part of the whole answer.

So there's two main cases :

**Case A.** Your value is in the main `ResourceDictionary` of your `App.xaml`

Where `App.xaml` is :

```
...
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="backgroundColor">LightBlue</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
...
```

If so read your value by using :

```
Application.Current.Resources["backgroundColor"]
```

**Case B.** Your value is in an external `ResourceDictionary` merged in your `App.xaml`

Where `App.xaml`is :

```
...
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Constants.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
...
```

Where `Constants.xaml` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Color x:Key="backgroundColor">LightBlue</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In this case use @earthling solution :

```
var mergedDict = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Where(md => md.Source.OriginalString.Equals("Styles/Constants.xaml")).FirstOrDefault();
var color = (Color)mergedDict["pressedColor"];
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. But be careful: you better do OriginalString.Contains("Contants.xaml") because right now, they added the assembly name after .xaml.

Answer (score 1):

The `ResourceDictionary` you want to reference has to be pulled into the application resources somehow. Either merge it into your `Application`'s resources (if it's common enough to be included all the time, at a slight hit to your app's initialization), or merge it into your `Page`'s resources (at a slight hit to the first page initialization).

You include foreign `ResourceDictionaries` with this syntax:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="path/to/resource.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <... your other resources for this page go here .../>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: I am merging it into my apps resources. I'm able to reference the resources in xaml, but not in code behind.

Comment: Then `(Color)Application.Current.Resources["MyBlue"]` should do it.